# BOOL being reset to NO in init method

Tags: ios, boolean, init, nsnotifications

I want to show a Now Playing button in a UINavigationController's bar.

I have a class (NowPlayingManager) that I am using to keep track of whether an audio file is currently being played.  I use a notification posted in another class (AudioViewController) to indicate playing status.  AudioViewController creates an instance of the NowPlayingManager with alloc/init and releases it.  In NowPlayingManager's target of the received notification I set NowPlayingManager's isNowPlaying Boolean to YES.

When the audio stops playing I send another notification that sets the isNowPlaying bool to NO.

However, each time the class is initialized the bool is set to NO, which makes sense because it is a new instance of NowPlayingManager and the Now Playing button is never displayed.

How can I get the isNowPlaying bool to persist through all instances of my NowPlayingManager?  Or, rather, Should I have the app delegate init the NowPlayingManager rather than AudioViewController so that only one instance is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course define the isNowPlaying as class member `+ (BOOL) isNowPlaying`. See 
[Objective-C: how to declare a static member that is visible to subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844958/objective-c-how-to-delcare-a-static-member-that-is-visible-to-subclasses) for more information on this.

But as you said already it seems to be more useful to create just one instance i.e. the singleton pattern. I suggest Matt Galaghers posting about singletons and his downloadable SynthesizeSingleton.h:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Comment: I went with a singleton with notifications.  I was trying to stay away from that choice but nothing else is practical.

Comment: Good choice. I use them pretty often for manager classes, event dispathers, facades,.. Ater a while you can't live without them :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should use `NSUserDefaults`. This remembers it even if you change class, close the app, etc.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"KeyName"];
```

And then check the bool with this:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"KeyName"] == YES]

{

    //Do whatever you would do when the bool is equal to YES

}
```